# How to call my mysqli_result class

Tags: php, mysqli

I create a mysqli_result class like that :

```
class mysqli_result{
    private $res;
    private $row;
    private $field=0;

private function __construct(){

}

static public function get($res,$row,$field){
    $res->data_seek($row); 
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
    return $datarow[$field]; 
}
```

}

The main problem is that I got three parameters while in the most of old mysql_result I got 2 parameters ($res,$field).

So I don't know what I suppose to put in the $row parameter.

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Why don't you just use mysqli extension of php?

Comment: `mysql_result` is already a class in PHP5. You should get a fatal error: class already declared.

Comment: mysqli_result doesn't exist anymore so I have to do this class. In fact, I tried to put 0 in $row, it seems working.